# How to get bluetooth device information paired with iphone

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, airpods

[image: I don't need to grant Bluetooth permission]

Can I get a list of bluetooth devices that have been paired with the iphone without use *"centralManager to scanForPeripherals..."* like the way **Wunderfind** used to find airpods.

As you can see, Wunderfind can find my airpods that I **don't need to grant Bluetooth permission**.

Comment: That app may be looking at available audio routes to find connected AirPods. You can't use Core Bluetooth without Bluetooth permission; it is an iOS 13 privacy requirement.  I just tried that app and it didn't find some airpods that weren't connected to my phone regardless of whether it has Bluetooth permission or not

Comment: This is exactly what I need to ask. Thank you so much - Paulw11!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrive the list of previously connected devices. You can find the related documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH6-SW10).

Comment: Have you ever used wunderfind app?  The first time you did not grant Bluetooth permission, the application found airpods.

Comment: No, I didn't use that app. The app might be finding airpods since the airpods are already connected to the system. It's mentioned in the Bluetooth programming guide in section `Retrieving a List of Connected Peripherals`. I haven't used these methods, hope it would be useful for you.

Comment: 1. What I need is to get the list of paired bluetooth devices without asking for bluetooth permission. (Airpods,...)
2. If you didn't use that app, so your answer is definitely wrong, because you do not understand my question.

Comment: If you want to use CentralManager, you must ask for permission to use bluetooth. As for Wunderfind, they don't need it. When you grant permission, they will scan other devices. If not, they can still get connected Airpods. (As Image above) I have not granted Bluetooth permission.

Answer (score 0):

The Wunderfind map appears to be looking at the available audio routes via the AV framework; It didn't detect nearby AirPods that weren't connected to my phone regardless of whether it had Bluetooth permission or not.

It could detect other Bluetooth headphones that were connected to my phone, without the app having Bluetooth permission.

From iOS 13 onwards, Bluetooth permission is required to use Core Bluetooth for privacy reasons.